# How to sort an arrayList of objects by their components in java

Tags: java

I am trying to sort an arrayList in two different ways, one by the areas of the objects inside the arrayList, and two, by the name(shape1, shape2) of the objects in the arrayList. The objects look like this when I print them into a file: shape1: (points, radius, etc...) area = 0.0 and the shapes keep going. I tried looking at other asked questions that are similar but all answered using Collections.sort. I am not sure I am supposed to be using this method. Here's some code I'm working with to give you an idea:

```
for (int i =0; i <shapes.size();i++){
    for (int j = 1; j<shapes.size(); j++){
        if (shapes.get(i).getShape().area() > shapes.get(j).getShape().area())
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how I should go about doing this. Any pointers? For the sorting by name I have to use:

```
shapes.get(i).getName()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework, I will not post any code.

If you are not allowed to use `Arrays.sort`, you can implement [*Selection Sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) - it is very simple, and you have the beginnings of it written in your code already. The idea is on each iteration of the outer loop on `i` to pick the smallest element in the segment from `i` to `shapes.size()` using the inner loop on `j`, and place that element at the `i`-th position of your array. Your inner loop should look like this:

```
for(int j = i+1 ; j<shapes.size(); j++)
//          ^--- this is what's changed
```

Now based on your `if` condition you either swap `j`-th element with `i`-th, or keep it in place and move on.

For sorting strings, use [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) method in your `if` condition.

Comment: how would i about placing it in the i'th position? .add? or .set?

Comment: @Milwaukoholic Use `set`. The classic swap goes like this: `Shape tmp=shapes.get(i); shapes.set(i, shapes.get(j)); shapes.set(j, tmp);`

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1**

You object can implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and use [Collections.sort(List list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) to sort.

```
public class Shape implements Comparable<Shape> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Shape o) {
        if(o == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(getName() == null || o.getName() == null) {
            return 0;
        } else if(getName() != null && o.getName() == null) {
            return 1;
        } else if(getName() == null && o.getName() != null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return getName().compareTo(o.getName());
    }
}

Collections.sort(shapes);
```

**Solution 2**

Create a class that implement [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use [Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

```
public class ShapeComparator implements Comparator<Shape> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Shape s1, Shape s2) {
        if(s1 == null || s2 == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
        }
    }
}

Collections.sort(shapes, new ShapeComparator());
```

Comment: I've un-suck-ifed your `Comparable` implementation. There was a missing generic type parameter, which is (I assume) what you were talking about with that "strong typing" nonsense. That said, neither implementation handles the case where the left-hand `getName()` call returns `null`. It'll NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class and the [`Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use something like this:

```
        Collections.sort(shapes, new Comparator<Object>() {
            public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
                Shape shape1 = ((Shape) obj1).getShape();
                Shape shape2 = ((Shape) obj2).getShape();

                String name1 = ((Shape) obj1).getName();
                String name2 = ((Shape) obj1).getName();

                Double area1 = shape1.area();
                Double area2 = shape2.area();

                int areaCmp = area1 - area2;
                if( areaCmp!= 0 ) {
                    return areaCmp;
                }

                return name1.compareTo(name2);
            }
        });
```

for more [info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)